# Label of composite component and o:validateMultipleFields

Tags: jsf, label, composite-component, omnifaces

I have the following composite component, and I want to use o:validateMultipleFields (o:validateAllOrNone more specifically).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  >

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="target" />
    <composite:attribute name="label"/>
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    <composite:attribute name="required" />
    <composite:attribute name="size" />
    <composite:attribute name="disabled" />
    <composite:attribute name="styleInput" required="false" />
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="input" targets="input" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" targets="#{cc.attrs.target}" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="keypress" event="keypress" targets="#{cc.attrs.target}" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:outputLabel id="label" for="input" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <p:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" 
          style="#{cc.attrs.styleInput}" size="#{cc.attrs.size}"
          disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}">
        </p:inputText>
        <p:message for="input" display="icon">
          <p:effect type="pulsate" event="load" delay="500" />
        </p:message>
    </h:panelGrid>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

The validation is working as expected, but the labels of the components specified on the `components` property are no showing. Instead it's showing the components id's.

```
<cetcomp:editar id="origem" label="Origem" size="10" />
<cetcomp:editar id="cst" label="CST" size="10" />
<o:validateAllOrNone id="origemCst" components="origem:input cst:input" showMessageFor="origem:input" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValidateMultipleFields` extracts the labels from the `label` attribute of the physical input components. Exactly those labels which would be used in standard JSF validation, too. You indeed have none, they are only set on the `<p:outputLabel>`.

Add them accordingly:

```
<p:inputText ... label="#{cc.attrs.label}">
```

An alternative is to use [`<o:outputLabel>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/outputLabel) instead of `<p:outputLabel>` as the OmniFaces one would automatically copy the label to the associated input component.

```
<o:outputLabel ... for="input" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
<p:inputText id="input" ... />
```

---

**Update**: it turns out that it actually still didn't work. The `#{cc}` wasn't available while `ValidateMultipleFields` is extracting the labels. This was fixed as per [issue 134](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/134) and it will be available in OmniFaces 2.1.

Comment: @BalucC, thanks for answering! Neither the o:outputLabel or label attribute did the job. In fact, if I hard code the label attribute of inputtext it works, but not if I use the `#{cc.attrs.label}`.

Comment: Oh, that's unexpected. I'll investigate it when time allows me. In the meanwhile, can you tell me which JSF impl/version is being used in your webapp?

Comment: Sure: Mojarra 2.2.8-jbossorg-1. Omnifaces 2.0. Thanks again!

Comment: One more info: using the validator in a inputtext outside a composite component works as expected, even with the `p:outputLabel`.

Comment: Fixed as per https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/134. Can you try today's 2.1 snapshot?

Comment: tested with 2.1 snapshot and it worked! Would you like to edit something in the answer before I accept it? Thank you!